# Delete cascade doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have these entities:

```
public class Ranking
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<FeederRanking> FeederRanking { get; set; }
}

public class FeederRanking
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int RankingId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RankingId")]
    public virtual Ranking Ranking { get; set; }

    public long ResultId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ResultId")]
    public virtual StudyResult StudyResult { get; set; }
}

public class StudyResult
{
  .....
}
```

**Database Context:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FeederRanking>()
    .HasRequired(f => f.Ranking)
    .WithMany(f => f.FeederRanking)
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.RankingId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

**Method responsible for the exclusion:**

```
public void Exclude(long idExclude)
{
    Ranking modelExclude = this.FindById(idExclude);

    try
    {
        Delete(modelExclude);
        Save();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public virtual void Delete(T entity)
{
     this.GetQuery.Remove(entity);
}

public virtual void Save()
{
     this.Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I need to delete my **Rankings** and **FeedersRanking**, but I received exception:

> integrity constraint (BD.FK2_FEEDER_RANKING) violated - located child
>   record

I've seen examples, so far in stack overflow, but I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

**What is the correct way to do cascade delete in this situation?**

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you have your `modelBuilder` backwards.  You're basically telling EF to delete a `Ranking` if the `FeederRanking` is deleted.  I could be wrong but I think you need to `Entity<Ranking>().HasMany().WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete()` something like that.

Comment: Show the code that *actually deletes* the data. Otherwise, this is guesswork. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my question, I added the method of deletion. @Ondrej Tucny

Comment: What is the content of StudyResult? And do you have a modelBuilder statement for the relationship between StudyResult and FeederRanking?

Comment: within StudyResult it has several properties for example: **id, name, date**.
Has a foreign key that points to an entity called Study.

**I do not have a modelBuilder for StudyResult and FeederRanking**

Comment: If this is database-first where EF isn't managing your schema then you will need to configure the FK between the two tables to cascade delete. AFAIK EF will not actually issue a Delete to the server /w Cascade on Delete enabled, but relies on the DB rule to perform the delete. With migrations this should update the schema to cascade delete. For optional relationships, (Nullable FKs) EF *will* update FK's to null, so this behaviour can be a bit misleading. Not sure why EF doesn't issue a Delete on cascading relationships, for DB-first it's more of a setting to notify EF to expect the cascade.